# Chrome wont open links from Slack or Terminal on MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal.app, macos-mojave, slack

When I click on links in Slack or run terminal commands like Jupyter Notebook, which previously have prompted Chrome to open a link, no link opens in Chrome.

macOS Mojave

Chrome 78.0.3904.108

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the simplistic answer, but restarting my machine fixed this issue for me.

I had the same issue: Terminal and Slack links suddenly stopped opening in Chrome. I tried clearing browser data in Chrome and changing various settings in Slack but those efforts didn't seem to change anything. Restarting my machine made the links work in both applications.

:shrug: